# Trying to find a related value with XSLT and Key function in the same XML document

Tags: xml, xslt, key

Good day all,

Hope you can help me with the following. I know XML a little and by trial and error and reading items on Stack Overflow, I have managed to create a working XSLT. 
The only thing that does not work is to get the Item Description ("BlaBla") next to the Item ID (AI0567). So this description must appear on the level of the "ns0:CarrierContent" line.

The problem (?) here is that the description is not a child, it is on the same level. Anyone knows if this is possible? Thank you in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns0:Message xmlns:ns0="####">
<ns0:Header>
</ns0:Header>
<ns0:Customers>
  <ns0:Customer>
    <ns0:Carriers>
      <ns0:Carrier>
        <ns0:ContentLines>
          <ns0:CarrierContent>
            <ns0:CustomerItemNo>AI0567</ns0:CustomerItemNo>
          </ns0:CarrierContent>
        </ns0:ContentLines>
      </ns0:Carrier>
    </ns0:Carriers>
  <ns0:Items>
    <ns0:Item>
      <ns0:No>AI0567</ns0:No>
        <ns0:Description>BlaBla</ns0:Description>
    </ns0:Item>
  </ns0:Items>
</ns0:Customer>
</ns0:Customers>
</ns0:Message>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-application progid=”Excel.Sheet”?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:ns0="###">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">   
  <xsl:text>progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:text>  
  </xsl:processing-instruction>
  <Workbook>
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Page1">
      <Table>
        <xsl:call-template name="XMLToXSL" />
      </Table>
    </Worksheet>
  </Workbook>
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template name="XMLToXSL"> 
<xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">   
  <xsl:text>progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:text>  
</xsl:processing-instruction>                               
<xsl:key name="DescriptionSearch" match="ns0:Message/ns0:Customers/ns0:Customer/ns0:Items/ns0:Item" use="@ns0:Message/ns0:Customers/ns0:Customer/ns0:Items/ns0:Item/ns0:No" />
<xsl:for-each select="/">
<Row>
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="String">
     <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Message/ns0:Customers/ns0:Customer/ns0:Carriers/ns0:Carrier/ns0:ContentLines/ns0:CarrierContent/ns0:CustomerItemNo" />
   </Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="String">
      <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Message/ns0:Customers/ns0:Customer/ns0:Carriers/ns0:Carrier/ns0:ContentLines/ns0:CarrierContent/ns0:ExternalCustomerItemNo" />
    </Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="String">
      <xsl:value-of select="key('DescriptionSearch',@ns0:Message/ns0:Customers/ns0:Customer/ns0:Carriers/ns0:Carrier/ns0:ContentLines/ns0:CarrierContent/ns0:CustomerItemNo)" />
    </Data>
  </Cell>
</Row> 
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/ns0:Message">
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are number of issues with the definition of the `xsl:key`

1. `xsl:key` needs to be a direct child of `xsl:stylesheet` and not within `xsl:template`
2. The "use" value starts with `@` which signifies an attribute, but `ns0:message` is not an attribute (and if it was, it wouldn't have child elements after it)
3. The "use" value should be relative to the what is being matched.

What this means, is that your `xsl:key` should look like this

```
<xsl:key name="DescriptionSearch" match="ns0:Message/ns0:Customers/ns0:Customer/ns0:Items/ns0:Item" use="ns0:No" />
```

In fact, in this case, you could simplify it to this, as you don't need to specify the full path to the match (not unless there are items elsewhere with different paths which you don't need matching)

```
<xsl:key name="DescriptionSearch" match="ns0:Item" use="ns0:No" />
```

As for using the key, your expression needs to be this (again note how the use of `@` as been removed)

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('DescriptionSearch',ns0:Message/ns0:Customers/ns0:Customer/ns0:Carriers/ns0:Carrier/ns0:ContentLines/ns0:CarrierContent/ns0:CustomerItemNo)/ns0:Description" />
```

So, you XSLT could look like this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:ns0="####">

<xsl:key name="DescriptionSearch" match="ns0:Item" use="ns0:No" />

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">   
  <xsl:text>progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:text>  
  </xsl:processing-instruction>
  <Workbook>
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Page1">
      <Table>
        <xsl:call-template name="XMLToXSL" />
      </Table>
    </Worksheet>
  </Workbook>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="XMLToXSL"> 
<xsl:for-each select="/">
<Row>
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="String">
     <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Message/ns0:Customers/ns0:Customer/ns0:Carriers/ns0:Carrier/ns0:ContentLines/ns0:CarrierContent/ns0:CustomerItemNo" />
   </Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="String">
      <xsl:value-of select="ns0:Message/ns0:Customers/ns0:Customer/ns0:Carriers/ns0:Carrier/ns0:ContentLines/ns0:CarrierContent/ns0:ExternalCustomerItemNo" />
    </Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="String">
      <xsl:value-of select="key('DescriptionSearch',ns0:Message/ns0:Customers/ns0:Customer/ns0:Carriers/ns0:Carrier/ns0:ContentLines/ns0:CarrierContent/ns0:CustomerItemNo)/ns0:Description" />
    </Data>
  </Cell>
</Row> 
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/ns0:Message">
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I would potentially simplify the final template to this (as this allows for the likely case of your XML containing multiple customers

```
<xsl:template name="XMLToXSL"> 
<xsl:for-each select="/ns0:Message/ns0:Customers/ns0:Customer/ns0:Carriers/ns0:Carrier/ns0:ContentLines/ns0:CarrierContent">
<Row>
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="String">
     <xsl:value-of select="ns0:CustomerItemNo" />
   </Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="String">
      <xsl:value-of select="ns0:ExternalCustomerItemNo" />
    </Data>
  </Cell>
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="String">
      <xsl:value-of select="key('DescriptionSearch', ns0:CustomerItemNo)/ns0:Description" />
    </Data>
  </Cell>
</Row> 
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/ns0:Message">
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Tim. 

Thanks a lot for your help! You have not only ensured that I now have a working xslt, but the most important thing is that I understand it better now. 
That is also the downside of the trial and error method, because I did not start with required basic knowledge, it cost me even more time as I point myself in the wrong direction every time. I will definitely going to learn myself the basics of XML (and XSLT), maybe someone can suggest me a good book, because with this special case I see how powerful XML/XSLT is. Thanks again!!!